# Run doesn't start the program

Tags: autoit

I've got a little Problem:

I'm new to AutoIt and wanted to write a program to automate the Teamviewer installation progress.

This is my "code":

```
Run ("teamviewer.exe","C:\WKS-Setup\")
```

In my "C:\WKS-Setup\" directory I have the script and the teamviewer.exe file, but it just doesn't seem to open (not even listed in the task manager).

I hope someone can help me out with my Problem :)

EDIT:

Here's the output from the SciTe Editor:

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\AutoIt3.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\AutoIt3Wrapper\AutoIt3Wrapper.au3" /run /prod /ErrorStdOut /in "C:\WKS-Setup\sdf.au3" /UserParams    
+>16:46:54 Starting AutoIt3Wrapper v.16.306.1237.0 SciTE v.3.6.2.0   Keyboard:00000407  OS:WIN_10/  CPU:X64 OS:X64  Environment(Language:0407)  CodePage:0  utf8.auto.check:4    # detect ascii high characters and if none found set default encoding to UTF8 and do not add BOM
+>         SciTEDir => C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE   UserDir => C:\Users\plamprecht\AppData\Local\AutoIt v3\SciTE\AutoIt3Wrapper   SCITE_USERHOME => C:\Users\plamprecht\AppData\Local\AutoIt v3\SciTE 
>Running AU3Check (3.3.14.2)  from:C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3  input:C:\WKS-Setup\sdf.au3
+>16:46:54 AU3Check ended.rc:0
>Running:(3.3.14.2):C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\autoit3.exe "C:\WKS-Setup\sdf.au3"    
--> Press Ctrl+Alt+Break to Restart or Ctrl+Break to Stop
+>16:46:55 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0
+>16:46:55 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.
>Exit code: 0    Time: 0.8446
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working:

The program needed to be run as Administrator, so I had to add the line

```
#RequireAdmin
```

I feel really stupid now.